# How to change color Explosive Candle on tradingview using pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I want to create an indicator that can give me a Explosive Candles
sign on the chart with different color.

I already get the script, but the problem is the script change color of all candles
All I want is only draw one Explosive Candle after a boring candles.

```
//@version=4
study("Demand and Supply Candles-open", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)
//Input
Sensitivity = input(title="LegoutStrength", type=input.float, defval=1.5, minval=1.0, maxval=2.0, step=0.5)

//Variable Declaration
Candle_Range = high - low
Body_Range = abs(open - close )

//Explosive Candles Logic
Bar_Lookback = 100
Volatility = atr(Bar_Lookback)

//Sensitivity = 1.5
Strength = Volatility * Sensitivity
bar_before=1
barcolor(Body_Range > Candle_Range * 0.6 and Candle_Range >= Strength ? color.black : na)

//Boring Candles or Basing Candles Body Range <= 50% of Candle Range
barcolor(Body_Range <= Candle_Range * 0.5 ? color.blue : na)
```

Comment: How can we help without seeing any of your code?

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. I have edited and added the code. Thanks